# Keras use multi-gpu without Model object (not for training)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

I have a bunch of tensor operations (matmul, transpose, etc..) I would like to run on a large dataset.
Since they are still matrix operations, and since I am using Keras generators to load the data batches, It would make sense to use GPUs to compute them.

Now, I've searched a while and I can't seem to find which is the correct way to use Keras to do parallel GPU operations, using generators, outside of the standard `Model` object interface.

Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? And why would you use Keras instead of TF with data API for low level ops?

Comment: @Sharky At the moment I am doing it on a single GPU, but it seems kind of inefficient, having multiple available. I was under the impression that using Keras.backend for everything was better for multi-backend compatibility/portability, but I may be wrong on this

Comment: It's ahrd to tell not knowing your particular application, but tf.data is generally recommended way of constructing a dataset. And you can just use `for device in ['/device:GPU:0', '/device:GPU:1']`
And please consider adding your code

Comment: @Sharky thanks for the info! sorry for the lack of code, it's work related stuff, but essentially is just a series of l2_normalization/matmul/transpose operations that I would like to compute over the whole dataset

Comment: Well, take a look at this example https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#using_multiple_gpus, maybe you'll be able to provide some context based on it